# Java: Is there any way to get context of single sign on done on local system through code?

Tags: java, authentication, httpurlconnection

My company uses multiple applications and single sign on using Microsoft login.

In my browser, I already login to application but when run incognito mode, it again ask for login and MFA.

Now i want to download the image in that application

```
try(InputStream in = new URL("https://bhuwhatwhere.tie.com/EmployeeImages/Profiles/AAHLENIU.jpg").openStream()){
        Files.copy(in, Paths.get("C://Integrator//AAHLENIU.jpg"));
    }
```

It returns on my local:

```
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. --><!DOCTYPE html><html dir="ltr" class="" lang="en"><head> <title>Sign in to your account</title>
All these url's return microsoft sign in page.
```

Is there way to download file using same browser contexts; either doing some registry changes (or do i need oauth etc.)? Because there are 4000 images and download single is mess.

Comment: The "official" way is to add whatever authentication your SSO provides to your app (OpenID and most other systems provide some "app flow" which can be used for desktop apps). The hacky-workaround way could be to grab the required cookies from your desktop browsers and hardcode them in your code. That one is a bit tricky and might require also following some redirects and storing temporary cookies so that all systems involved accept that you're authenticated. Another workaround is to download those images from your browser instead of from an external application via JS in the dev console.

Comment: Any idea where i can locate those cookies and how to reuse them, want to understand what to find in this context.

Comment: Each browser does it differently, but usually you can click on the left end of your address bar and click through some menu to see all cookies. Identifying the necessary ones for SSO/authentication can be tricky and really depends on the system.